# PHP check if DB entry is 1/0

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check in my If-Statement if the status is 1(true) or 0(false). The value is stored in a mySQL DB with tinyint.

The following code returns an error:

```
if($zeile['STATUS']=='1')
  {
      echo "<td align='center'>true;</td>";
  }
  else{
      echo "<td align='center'>false;</td>"; 
  }
```

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: STATUS in /home/u123210707/public_html/index.php on line 49'. line 49

is my If-statement

Comment: *"The following code returns an error:"* - being?

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined index: STATUS in /home/u123210707/public_html/index.php on line 49'. line 49 is my If-statement

Comment: Please give us the code before the if statement... like the query and how you fetch the data...

Comment: you'll need to provide the query for this, as well as db schema. No way for a concrete/definite answer here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($zeile['STATUS'] > 0)
  {
/* whatever */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your $zeile array there is no element like STATUS, that's why its give this error,

i think before if condition you must have to check array using print_r and check there is an element called STATUS.

Comment: yeah I took STATUS from the wrong Table *shame*